# append carriage return to string in jquery callback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, callback, append, carriage-return

I'm using jquery.scannerdetection.js to read barcodes from a scanner. Once the barcode is read, it puts the barcode data into a textbox but for some reason the Enter character is not included so my TextChanged event does not fire unless I manually press the enter key. I tried appending a carriage return and/or a new line character like this:

```
onComplete: function (barcode, qty) {
$('#<%= txtBarcode.ClientID%>').val(barcode + '\r');
},// main callback function
```

but the TextChanged event still does not fire. I've tried \n, \n\r but with no luck. I'm very new at this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: _"the Enter character is not included so my TextChanged event does not fire unless I manually press the enter key."_ What is `TextChanged event` ?Is `$('#<%= txtBarcode.ClientID%>')` an `input` element ?

Comment: The presence of a carriage return in a string doesn't cause any events to fire.  It's likely that programmatically changing the text simply doesn't cause that event to fire.  The question then becomes... Why do you *need* that event to fire?  If you need something to happen in the code in response to that event, why can't you just invoke that code here?

Comment: Pressing enter in a form (which is the behavior) triggers the form object's default button ID.  This iD is the button that is triggered by default, usually a submit button.  It's that default behavior that occurs...  so that would have to be the default behavior that gets triggered on barcode scan.  Are you sure it submits an enter action the same way as hitting the enter key?

Comment: I'm using VB.net / ASP.net to write this application. There is a textbox on the page called txtBarcode and the scanner puts the barcode data in that textbox. Once TextChanged (enter key is pressed triggers that event) a VB function is called to determine what kind of barcode was scanned and fills in the appropriate data (I'm scanning wine barrels and bay locations so that's why I need to call a function to determine which one was scanned). If I could call that VB function from within the jQuery code, I would, but I have no idea how to do that. Sorry, I'm very new at this.

Comment: As far as the default button goes, I'll see if I can make that work. Thanks.

Comment: Also, I do know that the scanner end character is [13]. If I place the cursor in the textbox and scan (the jquery.scannerdetection is ignored if the scan is done directly into an input control) the TextChanged event is fired and my page is populated as expected without having to manually press the enter key.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's an example](http://a.kabachnik.info/jquery-scannerdetection-tutorial.html) of using the jquery scanner detection.

It describes how to figure out the start and end characters your device is sending and then set the [EndChar](https://github.com/julien-maurel/jQuery-Scanner-Detection#endchar) property if it's not the default 9 or 13.

Be warned. The article's example uses his custom version and was written on Mar 18th, 2015. The last commit on github was Feb 3rd so I don't think his changes are rolled in (yet).

But I don't think his method to figure the characters relies on that.

Comment: This is actually where I found the code for what I'm trying to do. When it comes to the onComplete line of code, he offers this: onComplete: function(barcode, qty){ ... } // main callback function 
but I'm so new at this that I need something other than {...} to know what to do. Also, I did check and the end character is [13] so the scanner passes the expected data.